# Write Contacts in Xml file Using Service

Tags: android

Write Contacts to XML file Automatically using Service,When new one Contact added to the Default Contact Application is it possible?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

check [Contacts Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) to read contact data.
use [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) to listen the changes of contacts